# Does Apple ID is required to implement HealthKit Capabilities in Xcode project?

Tags: ios, watchos-2

with out Apple ID, Is it possible to use HealthHit Framework authorisation in Xcode project... When i am trying to create some project by using health kit capabilities its asking Apple ID. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to Sign-in using your apple ID registered on the Developer portal to access HealthKit.

You can checkout the complete list of App capabilities and which developer program you need to access them [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/).

Comment: Is it possible to create my own HealthkitStore for putting my health related information and later i can access it? so that, no need to provide Apple ID

Comment: I don't think that is an option. As far as I understand, you need to use the central HealthKit store.